# How change content of dist zip?

Tags: java, gradle

Gradle 7.1

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
 }
```

In my java project I create dist like this:

```
gradle distZip
```

As result create zip with the next content:

```
\app
\lib
```

OK, but I need to create one more folder (**data**) with file myfile.txt. Location of myFile.txt is on `build\resources\main\db\sqlite\myFile.txt`

So the result must be like this;

```
 \app
 \data\myFile.txt
 \lib
```

Is it possible?

Comment: is it strictly necessary for the file to come from resources folder? otherwise the docs suggest you can add your file to `src/dist`. https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:the_distribution

Comment: @criztovyl this help me: applicationDistribution.from("path_to_file") {
    into "data"
}